# Rise up a DEM of a fixed offset

Tags: qgis

I would like to move the whole DEM up of fixed offset (z=+0.613).

I am a beginner in QGIS. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use the raster calculator https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html to add a constant to a raster.

Comment: Michael i suggest you post your comment as answer since its spot on, so question can be closed.